# Requests to docker-machine created boot2docker host

Tags: docker, docker-machine

For fast development purposed I spin a MongoDB container on boot2docker on the standard MongoDB port and then I just connect to the database on the boot2docker ip on that port. Currently its

```
192.168.59.105:27017
```

With `docker-machine` I created a new `boot2docker`s named "host" which has the ip `192.168.99.113` where I installed `docker-compose` to spin MongoDB + a data container. But contrary to the default boot2docker, I cant seem to connect to Mongo on that machines ip (I get the ip with `docker-machine ip host`)

```
192.168.99.113:27017
```

In this case I don't get a connection, I don't even see the MongoDB warning message when I put that address on Chrome. Am I missing some critical configuration step to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Create a port forwarding for port `27017` in VirtualBox for your `docker-machine` named `host`.

Comment: If your question is a request for clarification, it should be a comment. If it's a suggestion, it should be written as an answer, not a question.